# How to pass extra data with Intent when using options menu's back arrow button?

Tags: android, kotlin

My "child" activity's options menu has a back arrow button, and my `putExtra` call isn't correctly saving my ByteArray data "`sn`" (or else, I'm somehow not passing the intent correctly when the back button is clicked). Here's the child activity's `onCreate` method:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    Log.d(TAG, "back button was pressed, writing ${sn.toHexString()}")
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SN, sn)
    setResult(REQUEST_CODE_SN, intent)
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

The `Log.d` line shows the data is correct above, and here's the parent activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // THE BELOW LINE CAUSES AN EXCEPTION:
    // getByteArrayExtra(EXTRA_SN) must not be null
    sn = intent.getByteArrayExtra(EXTRA_SN)
    Log.d(TAG, "sn is now ${sn.toHexString()}")
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
        R.layout.activity_foo
    )
}
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Take a look at [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: @kjellhaaland I do actually launch the child activity that way, but clearly I'm not passing the extra data back to the parent correctly. It's not accessible in Parent.onActivityResult either. I'll read the docs carefully to see if I can discern why.

Comment: If you are returning data when the user press back button and you are using setResult Method, you should be override onActivityResult and get that data from this method, not from onCreate method.

Comment: @rguzman, I'm beginning to see this is a design pattern issue with the way data flows. The parent activity needs `sn` to create the layout. When the child activity is launched, it's passed `sn` because it needs it too. When the back button is clicked, the parent activity needs `sn` again in `onCreate` to inflate the layout. What's the best way around this so that the parent activity can access `sn` for building the layout the first and second times? `Shared Preference` data storage instead?

Comment: Take a look at a recommended approach using ViewModels: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing